# ERROR no such table:

Tags: python

estoy empezando a aprender python, estoy creando una app de escritorio con py conectada a una SQlite, estoy utilizando DB browser. Espero me puedan ayudar a resolverlo! Gracias!

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

import sqlite3

class Product: 

      db_name = 'database.db'

      def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
          cursor = conn.cursor()
          result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
          conn.commit()
        return result

      def get_product(self):
        query ='SELECT * FROM Quees uantota ORDER BY name DESC'
        db_rows = self.run_query(query)
        print(db_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que dada la consulta:

```
'SELECT * FROM Quees uantota ORDER BY name DESC'
```

sqlite3 intenta buscar la tabla `Quees`, que lógicamente no existe. Si el nombre de tu tabla contiene espacios debes acotarlo:

```
query ='SELECT * FROM "Quees uantota" ORDER BY name DESC'
```